# Finding The Center of a View

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have an iphone app with 2 ViewControllers . Both screens(viewcontrollers) show a loading screen. I create the loading screen programmatically:

```
 UIView *loadingScreen = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,200,144,144)];
 loadingScreen.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width / 2.0, self.view.frame.size.height / 2.0);
     //{.. Other customizations to loading screen
     //   ..}
 [self.view addSubview:loadingScreen];
```

For some reason, the second viewcontroller's loadingScreen is significantly lower and it isn't centered on the screen. The first viewcontroller works perfectly and is dead center like I want.

The second viewcontroller is a UITableView and it shows the uinavigationbar, whereas the first viewcontroller doesn't show the uinavigationbar. Also, I use storyboard for my app.

I've outputted to the NSLog *self.view.frame.size.height* and *loadingScreen.center* in both instances and **THEY HAVE THE SAME COORDINATES!** So, not sure why it is showing up lower. Any ideas why the second loadingScreen is lower and how to fix? Thanks!

Comment: Dang man, harsh... I thought I worded this question very thoroughly. What makes it so bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that one screen displays a UINavigationBar while the other does not.  When you display a navigation bar, it offsets the rest of your view - in this case by shifting it down.

There are two quick fixes.  You can either adjust your center point up by the size of the UINavigationBar (65 pts - unless it's a custom UINavigationBar and you've changed its size) or you can set the "Adjust Scroll View Insets" value to false in the attributes inspector.

The latter is probably the easiest and comes most recommended.  Note though, that the top of your UITableView will now be underneath the UINavigationBar.

[image: Xcode example]

My final note would be that if you wanted to do it programmatically than in your UITableView's delegate you can call

```
- (BOOL)automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see... are there any other ways to get the frame height INCLUDING the size of the UINavigationBar? I just want this loadingScreen to be smack in the middle of the iPhone regardless of what size the screen is or if there's a UINavigationBar or not.

Comment: Sure... define a value for the y point based on the user's device.  If it's an iPhone 5/5s than set y = 568 / 2.  You'll need to define it for whatever devices you plan on running on though.

Comment: Does that answer your question?